# How to get the same result with PHP and JS using SHA512?

Tags: javascript, php

I have object like this and stored in PHP and JS in variabel **payloadTmp** :

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "id": "11701002"
    },
    "timestamp": 1623130669.833,
    "user_id": "test@comp.com",
    "target_data": "GET_DATA"
}
```

and i would like to hash using cryptojs [from this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) like this:

```
var trimmed_payload = JSON.stringify(payloadTmp).replace(/\s+/g, '');
var signature_raw = Secretkey + '-' + tstamp + '-' + trimmed_payload;
var signature_bytes = hmacSHA512(signature_raw,Secretkey);
var signature = Base64.stringify(signature_bytes);
console.log(signature)
```

and in my php code i would like to encode like this:

```
$trimmed_payload = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', serialize($data_arr['payloadTmp']));
$timestampToString = strval($data_arr['payload']->timestamp);
$signature_raw = $isExist->SecretKey . '-' . $data_arr['payload']->timestamp . '-' . $trimmed_payload;
$signature_bytes = hash_hmac('sha512', $signature_raw, $isExist->SecretKey);
$signature = base64_encode($signature_bytes);
var_dump($signature)
```

but i got a different output:

```
{fromJS: "xq98gaeDsTxi+vfdAGniB8Z5gvEQWLolkxMd/jVZJ5bMaSJ1jGtqTfAUztZyYXzQXo5fCcU/1cDFBqdYNLVdeg==",
 fromPHP: "afabc52c3df2c49d949d5949f9152a02f2bcd403c41ca333df…26f0dd8f19c80a287aafdfc4a56cc9b120df7561b4fd6f814"}
```

Could somebody give me a piece of advice of how to fix this?
Or it's normal output ?
The problem is i should get the same output from both.

Comment: It's an Object, and in JS, `payloadTmp.toString()` will amount to `[object Object]`. You need  `JSON.stringify(payloadTmp)` instead.

Comment: Now that you've fixed that part you should get very different output? Also, try putting a [mre] in the question.